# how many number of sphere from three point

Tags: math

there may be it very simple for masters.......

Suppose i have three point with x,y and z coordinate then how many number of sphear i can generate from these three point?(note: each sphere must contain all the three poins)

(e.g  we can generate only one circle from three point)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as @Ignacio said,

Lets have three points, now the number of sphere will be equal to the no of points that that lie at equal distance from those points.

And there will be a line, at equal distance from those points, and line will have infinite points.

UPDATES::

How many sphere can pass from a circle?? infinite... but only one smallest sphere and that will have the circle as diameter.

And as you said, three points make unique circle .. and so goes on and on.

Comment: i also like to saying to you also....though i have not mention in my
question......bit if i say all these three point
must be reside on diameter then what
should be your answer? Thanks....

Comment: Still there are infinitely many possible spheres. This addition adds no new information. Had you said the points must lie on a great circle, I would argue that would have added something new.

Comment: @Pritesh, you know that three points will form a plane. and joining will give you a tringle. Now, lets take the middle point of the triangle, that will be your center of circle. and you can calculate radius and thats the smallest shpere possible.

Comment: I thinking this way............  three points have always unique circle....and if this circle must be the diameter of sphere then must be unique sphere.............is it wrong?

Comment: @Pritesh there's only one sphere possible with your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

An infinite number.

Consider the simplest case, an equilateral triangle on a plane. Spanning the three points could be an almost-flat segment of a very, very large sphere, one facet of an icosahedron that fills another sphere, or a sphere that has each point at 120° across its equator, and any sphere in-between those.

Comment: though i have not mention in my question......bit if i say all these three point must be reside on diameter then what should be your answer? Thanks....